# Can't Download an ISO

Tags: iso

Is your website working? When I downloaded Ubuntu 22.04.3, I didn't get an iso file. I got this file: Unconfirmed 343295.crdownload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download didn't complete or else it stopped before completing.
To open PowerShell in Windows do the following:

1. Click the Start button.
2. Type *PowerShell* in the search bar.
3. Click the Windows PowerShell app.

To download the Ubuntu ISO in Windows run the following commands in PowerShell:

```
$URL="https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04.3/ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso"
$Path="C:\Users\<YOUR-USERNAME>\Downloads\ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso"
Invoke-Webrequest -URL $URL -Outfile $Path
```

In the second command replace `<YOUR-USERNAME>` with your username.

Comment: Ok, thanks karel. I downloaded it again and I'm going to give it a few more minutes to download and then use the command prompt if necessary.

Comment: I'm using a command prompt on a Windows and I don't have a terminal. When I paste in your code, I get the following:
'wget' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Should I install a terminal as shown in the following website?:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/install

Comment: When I tried to close my browser, it showed that the file was still downloading so I guess I just have to be patient and wait for it.

Comment: It's a big, big file. Yes, you must be patient.

Comment: Yeah, it took over an hour but I have it now. Thanks, Karel. I clicked "accept this answer". I hope I did it right. I see that you editted your answer to use the Windows PowerShell instead of the terminal. I'm just mentioning it so that the thread makes more sense.