# i am unable to get latest version of ubuntu 22.04.3 iso. can i get a bootable stick for dual installation along with windows11

Tags: dual-boot

I am unable to download latest version.  can i get boot-stick with latest version of linux release22.04.3 for dual installation with windows11.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: We are going to tell you to download the ISO and create the USB on your own.  But, you could maybe try a friend and have them download it for you.  Canonical used sell it on a disc or on USB, but they no longer have the store.  You can always look around at other places like eBay, etc.  but you will need to take those with a grain of salt since you will not know if they manipulated the USB or not.

Comment: You've not given any clues as to why you're unable to download the ISO (*its only a file though rather large*), which is available at many sites (*if you're having trouble with a specific site*), ie. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors  Ubuntu 22.04 is the 2022-April release; thus is **not** the latest (22.10 & 23.04 are both newer!), with 22.04.3 being the **latest respin* of the older 22.04 system. 22.04 is the *latest* LTS release of Ubuntu though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't Download an ISO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1483724/cant-download-an-iso) The accepted answer was edited from an [older revision 2](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1483726/revisions) that explains the process of downloading the Ubuntu 22.04.3 iso from Ubuntu.